# How to operate on value from collecting an IntStream inside a lambda function

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have an `IntStream` and I would like to get e.g. a list of items from some collection `things` whose index is in that stream.

I thought it would be as simple as

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).collect(Collectors.toList(
    _i -> things[_i]
))
```

but a problem of incompatible types (`<lambda parameter>` vs. int) appears.
`<lambda parameter>` can't be cast to Integer. This surprised me because a similar method `toMap` seems to work fine, if I add `boxed()` to the stream – then the type of the lambda parameter is java.lang.Object instead of `<lambda parameter>`:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    _i -> things[_i], _i -> 1
))
```

I am using Java 12.

How can I achieve similar behaviour in the `toList` method, or if what I am attempting is a bad idea altogether – why, and what would be a good alternative approach?

Comment: As an example `IntStream.range(0, 10)` is quite intuitive to be associated with `subList`.  (for a slice of data) I think it would be better to consider the example for such cases to be an `int[]` rather.

Comment: I don't understand why your problems is "of incompatible types". The method `Collectors.toList()` doesn't take parameters and the type `IntStream` has no `collect` method that accepts a `Collector`. Perhaps, there's a problem with the compiler's error reporting (which wouldn't surprise me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I would like to get e.g. a list of items from some collection things whose index is in that stream

For first question you have to use [mapToObj](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-)  intermediate operation, To get the elements from another `list` using `index` and collecting them into `List`

```
List<ObjectType> res = IntStream.range(0, 10)
                                .mapToObj(i-> things.get(i))   // or mapToObj(things::get)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> 2) This surprised me because a similar method toMap seems to work fine, if I add boxed() to the stream

For second question [boxed()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) will create a `Stream` of `Integer` (like `Stream<Integer>`), were `Stream` has [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) to collect the result into `Map` by using [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). Here is the [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors) with more information

**Stream**

```
<R,A> R collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)
```

**Collectors**

```
public static <T,K,U> Collector<T,?,Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
                                                Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)
```

Answer (score 1):

> This surprised me because a similar method `toMap` seems to work fine

You can make it with the same way of a Map by using `mapToObj` like so

```
List<Thing> collect = IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(_i -> things[_i])
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```